# How to build a polymorphism backend form in the Octobercms

Tags: forms, polymorphism, octobercms

First, thank you for my question.I designed a polymorphic model，like this

Content model

> id model_type model_id title ...

Post model

> id post_content

Video model

> id video_content

**Question is: The relationship in the model is well defined.I want to show the associated model, like Content+Post, Content+Video to a form.But I don't know how to do it?**

Comment: I am not sure but October Cms is not supporting that out of the box may be just look at this link it can help you (in backed forms)  : https://octobercms.com/forum/post/relation-controllers-for-polymorphic-relationships